# How do I edit the colors in a pre-existing VS Code theme?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I absolutely love the "Solarized Dark" theme, but how do I change the colors?

[image]

As you can see in this image, both "href" and the normal text "Click This" are grey.

I'd like to change the color of the normal text to white (or some another shade of it) for better legibility.

Here's the text of the image for your repro purposes:

```html
<a href="image.jpg">Click This</a>
```

Comment: read the Theme page in the VSC doc

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` action to open [the Scope Inspector](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector). Then click on the token you want to inspect. Then find out its textmate scopes. In this case, the href attribute is:

```
entity.other.attribute-name.html
meta.attribute.href.html
meta.tag.inline.a.start.html
text.html.derivative
```

You can take you pick of which one to use. For the sake of example, I'll pick `meta.attribute.href.html`.

And the text is:

```
text.html.derivative
```

Pick an appropriate textmate scope, and then use it in a token colour customization like so:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Solarized Dark]": {
        "textMateRules": [{
            "scope":"meta.attribute.href.html",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#BBBBBB"
            }
        },{
            "scope":"text.html.derivative",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#BBBBBB"
            }
        }],
    }
},
```

You can also set a `fontStyle` attribute.

See also [the docs for creating your own colour theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_creating-your-own-color-theme).